# How can i drag and drop nested lists in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop, nested-lists, splice

I have a list of items that can be dragged and dropped, and it's working fine. However, I'm having trouble dragging and dropping grouped elements across the index. The array comes as it is shown in the code I provided, and I can't change its structure.

What I want to achieve is to be able to drag and drop both tasks and groups, and when I drop a group into a task or another group, the group should become a child of that task or group.

Please let me know if you need any more information. The array come as it is shown, no other way.

```js
export default function App() {
  const dragRef = useRef<number>(-1);

  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { schema: "task", title: "Tarea A", level: 0, position: "1" },
    { schema: "task", title: "Tarea B", level: 0, position: "2" },
    { schema: "group", title: "Grupo 0", level: 0, position: "3" },
    { schema: "group", title: "Grupo 1", level: 0, position: "4" },
    { schema: "task", title: "Tarea 1", level: 1, position: "4.1" },
    { schema: "task", title: "Tarea 2", level: 1, position: "4.2" },
    { schema: "group", title: "Sub group 1", level: 1, position: "4.3" },
    { schema: "task", title: "Tarea sub 1", level: 2, position: "4.3.1" },
    { schema: "task", title: "Tarea sub 2", level: 2, position: "4.3.2" },
    { schema: "task", title: "Tarea C", level: 0, position: "5" }
  ]);
```

Here is the logic:

```js
const handleDragStart = (e: React.DragEvent, i: number) => {
  dragRef.current = i;
};

const getTargetIndex = (sourceLevel: number, indexTarget: number) => {
  let index = indexTarget;
  let target = items[index];

  while (target.level > sourceLevel) {
    index -= 1;
    target = items[index];
  }

  return index;
};

const getLastChildIndex = (targetIndex: number) => {
  let childIndex = targetIndex + 1;
  return childIndex;
};

const handleReSort = (indexTarget: number, indexSource: number) => {
  const source = items[indexSource];

  let targetIndex = getTargetIndex(source.level, indexTarget);
  const target = items[targetIndex];

  const isSameLevel = target.level === source.level;
  const isAnyAGroup = target.schema === "group" || source.schema === "group";

  const _items = [...items];

  if (isSameLevel && !isAnyAGroup) {
    _items.splice(indexSource, 1);
    _items.splice(targetIndex, 0, source);
    setItems(_items);
    return;
  }

  if (isSameLevel && isAnyAGroup) {
    const targetIsGroup = target.schema === "group" || source.schema === "group";
    const targetIsLast = targetIndex + 1 === items.length;
    const targetIsEmpty =
      !targetIsGroup || targetIsLast ? true : items[targetIndex + 1].level === target.level;

    const sourceIsGroup = source.schema === "group";
    const sourceIsLast = indexSource + 1 === items.length;
    const sourceIsEmpty =
      !sourceIsGroup || sourceIsLast ? true : items[indexSource + 1].level === source.level;

    // Remove the source element from _items list
    _items.splice(indexSource, 1);

    // Insert the source element into its new position
    if (targetIsEmpty && sourceIsEmpty) {
      // If both target and source elements are empty, insert the source element at the target index
      _items.splice(indexTarget, 0, source);
      setItems(_items);
    } else {
      if (!sourceIsEmpty && !targetIsEmpty) {
        // If both target and source elements have children
      } else if (!targetIsEmpty) {
        targetIndex = getLastChildIndex(targetIndex);
        _items.splice(targetIndex, 0, source);
        setItems(_items);
      } else {
        // If only the source element has children
      }
    }
  }
};

const handleDrop = (e: React.DragEvent, indexTarget: number) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!dragRef || dragRef.current === -1) return;

  const indexSource = dragRef.current;
  handleReSort(indexTarget, indexSource);
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <ul>
      {items.map((item: any, i: number) => (
        <li
          draggable
          className={`item-level-${item.level} schema-${item.schema}`}
          onDragStart={(e: React.DragEvent) => handleDragStart(e, i)}
          onDrop={(e: React.DragEvent) => handleDrop(e, i)}
          onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
        >
          {item.title}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```